# Cross section of parabolic satellite in Quadratic Functions

Tags: quadratics

A parabolic satellite dish has a cross section that can be modelled by the equation
$$y = 0.05\,x^2.$$
While still in the shipping yard, the dish fills with rain. The rain forms a circular puddle with a diameter of $2$m. What is the depth of the water at the centre of the dish?

Comment: Draw a picture of the parabola, and then use the diameter given to find the value of x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y = 0.05x^2$. If you fix the bottom apex of the dish is (0,0). The diameter of the circular puddle is 2m. The value of x = 1 (diameter/2). Substitute the value of x to find the value of y  = 0.05*1 = 0.05. The depth of water at the center of the dish is 0.05m.

Comment: Brilliant! So it was a matter of identifying y as representing the depth and x as the radius. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome!